# mysql outer left join query too slow

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

in order to show only last message (table: messages), i am using a correct but slow query on tables calderone (lot is key field) and messaggi (lot,ope_nr are key fields).

```
SELECT *
FROM calderone s1
Left outer JOIN (
  SELECT lot,ope_nr,messaggio, MAX(datamex)
  FROM messaggi s2
  GROUP BY lot,ope_nr ) as s3
using (lot,ope_nr)
```

Is there any way to speed up the query?

Comment: why using in the end of query?

Comment: Can you show us your full table definitions?  Your inner query currently has a problem, by the way.

Comment: You should join messaggi to itself

Comment: Hi, calderone contains lot info (key table is lot).

Comment: Hi all, calderone contains lot info (keys are lot, ope_nr). messaggi contains all messages related to lot,ope_nr.   Messaggi contains message date (datamex). I nees a report of all calderone info more last message (max message date)

Comment: using (lot, ope_nr)  means: calderone.lot=messaggi.lot ans calderone.ope_nr=messaggi.ope_nr

Comment: My answer was wrong ! I have deleted it... will repost if I find a better answer